# How to encrypt both EBS volumes on AWS EMR nodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I need to encrypt all EBS volumes for all EC2 instances that are running in our EMR cluster.

**We don't use any additional EBS volumes**, so I only need to enable encryption on the root EBS volume on each EMR node. (Or so I thought)

The steps I took to accomplished this (per the [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-data-encryption-options.html) in AWS documentation):

1. Copy the base AMI that is used by AWS EMR (it is the same image for master+core nodes)
2. Enable EBS encryption on my copy (By checking the box "Encrypt target EBS snapshots")
3. Re-provision the EMR cluster using my new custom AMI: `CustomAmiId: {myNewAmiId}`

It succeeded. However, when I analyze any of my nodes (master or core nodes), I see two EBS volumes. One is encrypted, **one is not**:

There are 3 entries under EC2 block devices:

1. `/dev/xvda` (Root device) (Encrypted)
2. `/dev/xvda` (Block device) (Encrypted) (This is just the same volume as #1)
3. `/dev/sdb` (Block device) (**Not encrypted**) -- What is this volume?

**I want to know: What is this EBS volume that is mapped to `/dev/sdb`? And how can I encrypt it?**

Details:

- EMR version: 5.7.0
- EC2 hardware: c4.8xlarge

Comment: This might be the device that is mounted to the /emr partition, a 5GB partition that is carved out of the first volume (the remaining space of which is mounted to /mnt). The /emr partition is used for internal EMR components and logs and presumably does not need to be encrypted.